# Share internal hdd through usb

Tags: hard-drive, nas, samba, usb-storage

I would like to make a NAS on my single-board pc with capability to connect my smart TV to this HDD through USB to watch movies.

Actually I need this -> internal HDD with usb2sata adapter ---> USB1(PC):USB2(PC) ---> TV. 
I know it`s impossible to use one HDD with 2 pc simultaneously also I know It`s possible to share it through network (example: SAMBA), so I would like it to share not through network but through another USB. How can I do it?

Comment: this will not be possible, for the same reason that you can't have two PCs using a single drive simultaneously. an OS coordinates the operation of a drive, and handles things like concurrency controls in software. if one computer opens a file for write access, it locks the file, but that lock is not visible to another OS accessing the drive, so the two OS's cannot coordinate their use of the resource. Samba works because a single computer (the fileserver) is handling all the IO operations, and brokering access to the files and volumes for remote users, but not the disk itself.

Comment: some options include: using a video card with a HDMI out, and connecting that to the TV or getting a device like a WD Live TV box to attach to the TV, which can itself access samba shares. I'd go with the HDMI cable. its not really very differant from using a USB cable, and then you are not forced to deal with the restrictions of the poorly programmed TV software. for instance codec support, alternative players, subtitle support, audio preferences, etc are things you can adjust on a PC, but are set in stone in the TVs firmware.

Comment: I don't understand how you can say "I know its impossible to use one hdd with 2 pc simultaneously" [you mean networking aside]  and you say "I would like it to share..through another usb.  ". Why are you saying it's impossible and asking how.

Comment: You don't mention the OS, distribution, and version number of the PC.  If Linux, a SAMBA setup is possible as well as NFS but not a direct attachment since this would cause near immediate data corruption.

Answer (score 0):

@Frank Thomas. I do not need that my TV would have a host/master access to hdd I need  only that TV would have an access to shared folder to get movies like in samba, when folder/disk shared at the same hdd, hdd can be used by both but by network users so I need this sharing but not by network but another host usb. I do not have a knowledge at low level so I`m trying to modulate any possible option.
I know that I can use it as DLNA, but I don`t want to use resources of my pc cause of it will be used as well as web, mail server etc. Also as I said before, It will be different single board pc, so it will be very uncomfortable to connect every time mouse, keyboard to play/control movies, as well as not comfortable place (behind TV). Thx for answer.

@barlop As well as I do not understand why like u people r writing comments just for spam without any offers or arguments. If u dont want, or do not have answer pls go to another post and help.

@mdpc OS is ubuntu/xubuntu 14.04. Thx for answer.

Comment: you are demanding way way way too much from one box.